# php echo text surrounded by an image

Tags: php, html

If im echo'ing some text back in php, how can i put a background image to each piece of text echo'd, where the image adjusts height depending on the length of the echo.

This is my code below just to try explain things a bit better. Then with each row i want the image speech.png to be behind the text?

```
function populate_shout(){
    global $dbh;
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM shout ORDER BY id DESC limit 20");
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
                echo '<li>';
                echo '<span class="date">&nbsp;<br/>'.$row['date_time'].'</span>';
                echo '<span style="font-size:12px;" class="name">&nbsp;<b>'.$row['name'].'</b></span>';
                echo '<span style="color:black;" class="message">&nbsp;<br/>'.$row['message'].'</span>';
                echo "img src="images/speech.png" width="60" height="20"";
                echo '</li><br/>';
                }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: this question has nothing to do with PHP. First learn HTML and only then move to PHP

Comment: Just to be totally correct, the lime with echo "img src", needs backslashes before quotes around image name, i.e. \"images/speech.png\". :) Same with width and height, or just change internal quotes to single quotes

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to apply the background images to the span class

```
span.date, span.name,span.message {
    background-image: url(images/speech.png) no-repeat;
}
span.name {
    font-size:12px;
}
span.message {
    color:black;
}
```

And avoid to use inline style